# UserManager Argument Type not within bounds

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm rewriting an MVC3 application using MVC5 with EF6 and attempting to also migrate the membership and roles API to Identity 2.  I've followed several guides but am now receiving build errors with which I need assistance.

My AccountController in part is as follows:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
    {
    }

    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
```

My UserManager is as follows:

```
public class UserManager : UserManager<User>
{
        public UserManager()
            : base(new UserStore<User>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
        {
            this.PasswordHasher = new SQLPasswordHasher();
        }
}
```

My ApplicationDbContext is as follows:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        this.Database.Log = Logger;
    }

    private void Logger(string log)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(log);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        var application = modelBuilder.Entity<Application>();
        application.HasKey(t => t.ApplicationId).ToTable("Applications");

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserDbProfile>().ToTable("Profiles");

    }

    public virtual IDbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<UserDbProfile> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

My User model is as follows:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public User()
    {
        CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        IsApproved = false;
        LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        LastActivityDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        LastPasswordChangedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        LastLockoutDate = MinSqlDate;
        FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart = MinSqlDate;
        FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart = MinSqlDate;
        Profile = new ProfileInfo();
    }

    public System.Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? LastActivityDate { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PasswordQuestion { get; set; }
    public string PasswordAnswer { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? LastLockoutDate { get; set; }
    public int FailedPasswordAttemptCount { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart { get; set;}
    public int FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart 
    { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public ProfileInfo Profile { get; set; }

    private static readonly DateTime MinSqlDate = 
    DateTime.Parse("1/1/1754");
}
```

The specific errors received are similar to:

```
Error   16  
Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager' is less accessible than method 
'Controllers.AccountController.AccountController(Microsoft.AspNet.
Identity.UserManager<Controllers.ApplicationUser>)'
```

Note that I've already created new tables in the database that migrated the old membership and roles for use with Identity 2.

What must be done to resolve the errors and ensure that the new Identity 2 methods are working correctly?

**Update**
My AccountController code is now as follows:

```
public AccountController()
    : this(new UserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
    {

    }
```

UserManager is as follows, in part:

```
public class UserManager : UserManager<User> 
{
    private UserStore<Controllers.ApplicationUser> userStore;

        public UserManager()
            : base(new UserStore<User>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
        {
            this.PasswordHasher = new SQLPasswordHasher();
        }


}
```

Build error states:

```
Error   19  'UserManager' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
```

Note that the ApplicationUser controller was created but doesn't have any methods implemented.  Is this controller, needed?  Or, can I remove it and references to it?

Comment: Your error appears to have something to do with your account controller, it may be helpful to see those methods as well.

Comment: I added the AccoountController to the original post.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AccountController needs to take your `UserManager`, not `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` which is part of the framework:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController()
        : this(new UserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
    {
    }

    public AccountController(UserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public UserManager UserManager { get; private set; }
```

Also I noticed that in controller you have `ApplicationUser`, but your user object is actually `User`. Make sure you are consistent with your classes.